# How to increase display time of DataGridView's Column header tooltips?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I currently set the tooltips of my DGV column headers like so:

dgv.Columns(1).ToolTipText = "Some Text"

Currently, the text will be displayed for about 5 seconds.  I want to increase it to 10 seconds.  I am setting my tool tips like this because for each of my DataGridViews, I will have about 20 separate Tool Tip Headers for 20 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no publicly exposed property that will allow you to change the [ToolTip.AutoPopDelay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.autopopdelay(v=vs.110).aspx).  You will need to resort to Reflection and the [DataGridView source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2cc4e2a42be6fd3c) to hack a solution.

The DataGridView has a field named `toolTipControl` that is an instance of [DataGridViewToolTip](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewToolTip.cs,5968dcbe21dfabde).  `DataGridViewToolTip` has a field named `toolTip` that is a `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip`.  This field is initialized in the `DataGridViewToolTip.Activate` method.

Using this information, the following code can be constructed to change the `AutoPopDelay`.

```
Private Shared Sub SetDGVToolTipDelay(dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim fi_toolTipControl As FieldInfo = GetType(DataGridView).GetField("toolTipControl", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    Dim toolTipControl As Object = fi_toolTipControl.GetValue(dgv)

    Dim fi_ToolTip As FieldInfo = fi_toolTipControl.FieldType.GetField("toolTip", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    Dim tt As ToolTip = CType(fi_ToolTip.GetValue(toolTipControl), ToolTip)
    If tt Is Nothing Then
        tt = New ToolTip
        tt.ShowAlways = True
        tt.InitialDelay = 0
        tt.UseFading = False
        tt.UseAnimation = False
        fi_ToolTip.SetValue(toolTipControl, tt)
    End If
    tt.AutoPopDelay = 10000 ' 10 seconds
End Sub
```

Just call `SetDGVToolTipDelay` and pass the DataGridView instance that you want to change the delay on.

Comment: @theMoreYouNgo, if this resolves your issue, consider marking it as answered so that others know that you are no longer seeking a solution.

Comment: In WPF `<Button ToolTip="Create a new file" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="5000" Content="Open" />`